# Flipping sprite in unity with weird movement script

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, sprite, velocity

I want to flip my sprites depending on which direction they are going and then stay in that position until they move again. I've tried velocity detection and the flipping the sprites accordingly, but since my movement is not by force but by changing position it can't detect velocity (I think), so any suggestions would be helpful.

Here's the movement script I've got so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    //DRAG AND DROP
    bool isBeingDragged = false;
    //POSITIONS AND TARGET
    public float speed = 0.5f;
    float timer = 0f;
    public float waitTime;
    public float distanceToAchieve = 0.2f;
    bool isFollowing = true;
    bool isWaiting = false;
    //GOAL TARGET
    public GameObject goalGameObject;
    Vector2 target;
    public Vector2 bounds = new Vector2(1.75f, 3);
    private Vector2 RP;
    private float startPosX;
    private float startPosY;

    void Start()
    {

        if (this.gameObject.tag == "1")
        {
            transform.position = RandomizePosition();
        }
        target = RandomizePosition();
        isFollowing = true;


    }
    private void Update()
    {

        if (!isBeingDragged)
        {
            if (!isWaiting && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target) < distanceToAchieve)
            {
                isWaiting = true;
                isFollowing = false;
                RandomizeGoal();
            }
            if (isWaiting)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                if (timer > waitTime)
                {
                    timer = 0f;
                    isWaiting = false;
                    isFollowing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isFollowing && !isBeingDragged)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (isBeingDragged)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos;
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

            this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, mousePos.y - startPosY, 0);
        }

    }
    Vector2 RandomizePosition()
    {
        RP = new Vector2(transform.position.x - Random.Range(-1f, 1f), transform.position.y - Random.Range(-1f, 1f));
        if (RP.x < bounds.x && RP.x > bounds.x * -1 && RP.y < bounds.y && RP.y > bounds.y * -1)
        {
            return RP;
        }
        else
        {
            return new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
    void RandomizeGoal()
    {
        waitTime = Random.Range(2, 10);
        target = RandomizePosition();
        goalGameObject.transform.position = target;
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isBeingDragged = true;

        Vector3 mousePos;
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        startPosX = mousePos.x - this.transform.localPosition.x;
        startPosY = mousePos.y - this.transform.localPosition.y;
    }
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isBeingDragged = false;
        GetComponent<Merging>().CheckNearest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isFollowing && !isBeingDragged)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (isBeingDragged)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos;
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

            // capture the current position of target
            // by the way, why you use "loclPosition" for moving ?? 
            // I don't thinkg this is appropriate. 
            var currentPos = this.gameObject.transform.localPosition;

            var newPos = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, mousePos.y - startPosY, 0);


            // then compare this with new position
            bool isLeftSided = false;
            if (newPos.x > currentPos.x)
            {
                isLeftSided = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isLeftSided = false;
            }
            // And figure out the direction . in this example, I wrote just right-left case
            // use the y pos for up and down  
            // then flip the sprite ( this case, default is right sided )
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX. = isLeftSided;

            this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, mousePos.y - startPosY, 0);
        }

    }
```